# select part of a jpeg image to display in html

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am quite new to web programming in general and I was wondering how I could show a part of an image on a html page (similar to sprites - i.e without modifying it in photoshop/gimp etc).

So, I have the following [image](http://www.inventlayout.com/Uploads/aj2w103qhnc3186/Facebook-64-thumb.jpg), where, I would like just the "Connect with Facebook" including the rounded corners.

How can I achieve this using HTML/CSS?

I tried to copy relevent bits using GIMP and then exporting it back to jpeg etc.. but the final image seems to loose quality.

At the end I do something like (using twitter bootstrap):

```
<div class="row-fluid pagination-centered">

        <ul class="thumbnails">
          <li class="span4 offset4">
            <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img alt="Facebook stuff" data-src="holder.js/273x42" style="width: 273px; height: 42px;" src="fb.jpg">
            </a>
          </li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

Therefore, I would like to know how to show that part of the image without modifying the image itself.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/5VQBD/1/

```
.fb-connect{width:280px; height:46px; background:url('http://www.inventlayout.com/Uploads/aj2w103qhnc3186/Facebook-64-thumb.jpg') no-repeat -46px -126px; -moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;}



<div class="fb-connect"></div>
```

Comment: Jeez! that is excatly what I was looking for. You are a genius.. Thanks for saving me hours of frustration. I almost gave up on this - since modifying the image on gimp simply did not work! Thanks again so much. Accepted your answer

Comment: Just a quick question: Would it possible to make this `<div>` clickable? i.e inside say an `a` tag or something. Sorry if my question sounds stupid. I am rather bad at HTML!

Comment: Thanks so much San: you have been unbelievably helpful!. Thanks again.

Comment: for some reason, the hover effect does not work (not that I need it - but it does look attractive) when I include it in my CSS. On jsfiddle, it works fine ofcourse. Ideas?

Comment: I can't comment anything unless I see your css

Comment: Missed your above comment. Just wanted to say everything works fine - was my fault. my CSS got overridden!