# HTML display bottom left quarter of the image

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in HTML coding and I'm trying to display just a part of an image. I'm displaying the image this way:

```
<img id="theImg" style="width:100%;" src="https://'myimage.jpg'" />
```

but I really don't know how to display just bottom left quarter of the image. It is even possible without making a new picture with the cropped image?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461021/display-a-part-of-image-css-html or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146100/select-part-of-a-jpeg-image-to-display-in-html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [select part of a jpeg image to display in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146100/select-part-of-a-jpeg-image-to-display-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the size of your image, you can put it into a container which has half the width and height of the image and use `position: absolute;` and the settings shown below:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/fa0" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a div element that has a background image and then just apply a few css changes to that div like so:

```
#theImg {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('https://myimage.jpg');
  background-position: bottom left;
}
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kekwdy2L/3/

Answer (score 0):

Use `background-image` with `background-position`:

```css
#my-image {
  background-image: url('https://i0.wp.com/lovecuteanimals.objects.cdn.dream.io/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Cute-Netherland-Dwarf-Rabbit.jpg?w=1160');
  background-position: -220px -80px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="my-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
div {
height: height you want;
width: width you want;
background-image:url("image you want");
</style>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you know the size of the image in pixels, you can use a [css clip](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_clip.asp).

Note, `clip` is officially deprecated in `css` specification, however its replacement `clip-path` currently has very low browser support.

Another way of achieving crop is placing the `<img>` tag within a `<div>` as shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/493329) answer.